# Can not use apt-get update for Debian

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, terminal

I cannot access full permission and terminal always show message below.

```
alex@debian:/$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: your user account is not running with root privledges , so you either need to login as root (`su root`) to run the command, or run `sudo apt-get update` instead, assuming sudo is available and has been configured for your user.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there i got the same issue :

i install Debian :

i create an user debian,and i added to the root group :

```
debian@03-:~$ groups debian
debian : debian root sudo
```

and i try to update :

```
debian@03-:~$ sudo apt-get update
-bash: sudo: command not found
debian@03-:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

someone can have what i do wrong please ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo` to gain elevated permissions, or login as root (typically not recommended unless you know what you're doing).

Try using `sudo apt-get update` instead.

When you say you can not access full permission, if you mean the sysadmin does not allow `sudo` or logging in as root, you would need to get them to run the update.